# What criteria to look for when placing pokemon to defend gyms?

Tags: pokemon-go

What kind of pokemon should I place in the gyms? There is this gym defence tier list which has pokemon with high hp in it.

[image: Gym defend tier list]

Is that the only thing we should look for? Does DPS, attack moves, CP matter or is hp the most important thing?

Comment: Quick thought: Defending Pokemon attack every 1.5 second. No one has proven it to be adjusted, so it would make sense to put Pokemon with **higher damage slower attacks instead of lower damage faster attacks**.

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 main criteria: The first being high hp, for obvious reasons. The second criteria is charges that charge fast and have a high base damage to take full advantage of the 1.5 attackrate. The third one is a high Defense-DPS, explained in depth [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277288/is-damage-from-defending-pokemon-normalized-for-slow-and-fast-attacks/277364#277364). But to simplify it: a high base damge is generally better.

The highest Tier actually isn't simply the highest hp Pokémon - it is more of a coincidence that the high hp Pokémon also have a higher base damage.

Comment: So in that case is this tier list inaccurate?

Comment: Not really. I browsed the net a bit and found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4skafz/best_attackers_and_defenders_analysis/) reddit post with a rather accurate tier list in my opinion, so feel free to check it out.